# Ошибка mysql ubuntu

Tags: sql, mysql

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)root@20635:~#
```

как исправить? впервые столкнулся

Comment: ss -plna | grep mysql  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- не запущен сам мускул
- куда-то делся интерфейс lo

Comment: lo не используется когда соединение по сокету.